# Puppeteer headless chrome stopped working suddenly

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to open a url, which is  heavy and take about 2-3 minutes to complete the process the all ajax request on that page.  it was working before and it stopped suddenly. Nothing has been changed. if i hit that url directly on my system it works properly. but i need to run via puppeteer.

here is the code which i am using

```
var searchURL = "url which i m hitting";
         try {
             
              var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {flags: 'a'});
                logStream.write('puppeteer PDF start Initial line...');
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                    dumpio:true,
                executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
                args: ['--enable-logging --v=1'],
                headless: true,
                });
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
                await page.goto(searchURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 });
                logStream.write(' Browser open for  PDF start ');
                await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
                logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 1');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
                    logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 2');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
                    logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 3');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
                    logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 4');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                    logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 5');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                    logStream.write('puppeteer close for PDF 6');
                    
                        await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 7');
                    await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 8');
                await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 9');
                await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 10');
                await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 11');
                await page.waitForTimeout(500);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 12');
                await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
                logStream.write('puppeteer Final close for PDF 13');
                await page.waitForTimeout(50000);
                res.send("hello");
            } catch (err) {
                
                    var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {flags: 'a'});
                    logStream.write('PDF Error  '+err);
                    console.log(err);
                    
            }
```

Logs file created till  "puppeteer close for PDF 6" after that no log generated. ; if i add await time in one go even its not working.

No log found on serve as well. Not sure if i am doing something wrong

Comment: `waitForTimeout` is generally a bad idea -- it's always race condition. Spin on a predicate with `waitForFunction`, a selector with `waitForSelector`, or an xpath with `waitForXPath`. That said, it's hard to say much else without seeing a [mcve] or a link to the site in question. As an aside, the code should use loops instead of retyping all of the code many times.